# Sed : select lines between two timestamps

Tags: shell-script, sed

I want to select lines between two timestamps - 60 minutes before and now

My command is

```
sed -n '/"$(date -d '60 minutes ago'  +"%H:%m")"/,/"$(date -d  +"%H:%m")"/p'  /var/www/html/glpi/files/_log/event.log/
```

But i get :

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unterminated address regex
```

Comment: The shell will not expand the command substitution within a single-quoted string. Also note that a single-quoted string can not contain single quotes.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you are trying to do. Should we assume you are using Linux? I guess so since `date -d` isn't very common. But `date -d  +"%H:%m"` is not a valid `date` command, what is that supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

A sed script like you have would rely on exactly the beginning and ending timestamps being present in the input. Don't do that - use awk for `<=` comparisons instead so it'll work even if the exact beginning and ending timestamps aren't present in the input, e.g.:

```
awk -v beg="$(date -d '60 minutes ago' +'%H:%m')" -v end="$(date +'%H:%m')" '(beg <= $0) && ($0 <= end)' /var/www/html/glpi/files/_log/event.log/
```

That's just an untested guess at what you need since you didn't provide any sample input/output for us to test with. Whether it works for you or not will mainly depend on where the timestamps occur in your input (I'm assuming it's at the start of each line) but the script can be trivially tweaked for wherever that is.